# Python : I am not able to access individual elements inside sublist. The entire sublist is displayed as single element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

My Code :

```py
import ast

with open('input.txt', 'r') as file :
    filedata = file.read()

    filedata = filedata.replace('|', ',')

    out = []
    buff = []
    for c in filedata :
       if c == '\n':
           out.append(''.join(buff))
           buff = []
       else:
           buff.append(c)
    else:
       if buff:
           out.append(''.join(buff))

    list = [[i] for i in out]
    print(list)
```

Input :

```
10|1|SELL|toaster_1|10.00|20  12|8|BID|toaster_1|7.50 
13|5|BID|toaster_1|12.50  15|8|SELL|tv_1|250.00|20  16
17|8|BID|toaster_1|20.00  18|1|BID|tv_1|150.00  19|3|BID|tv_1|200.00 
20 21|3|BID|tv_1|300.00
```

Expected Output

```
[["10","1","SELL","toaster_1","10.00","20"],
["12","8","BID","toaster_1","7.50"], 
["13","5","BID","toaster_1","12.50"],
["15","8","SELL","tv_1","250.00","20"],  ["16"], 
["17","8","BID","toaster_1","20.00"], 
["18","1","BID","tv_1","150.00"],  ["19","3","BID","tv_1","200.00"], 
["20"], ["21","3","BID","tv_1","300.00"]] "
```

The Output I am getting:

```
[['10,1,SELL,toaster_1,10.00,20'],
['12,8,BID,toaster_1,7.50'], ['13,5,BID,toaster_1,12.50'],
['15,8,SELL,tv_1,250.00,20'], ['16'], ['17,8,BID,toaster_1,20.00'],
['18,1,BID,tv_1,150.00'], ['19,3,BID,tv_1,200.00'], ['20'],
['21,3,BID,tv_1,300.00']] [Finished in 0.1s]
```

I want to access individual elements within sublist, eg, SELL, or
toaster, but I am not able to access them. Can someone advice please?

Comment: You seem to create strings, not lists. You might try using `lis = [i[0].split(',') for i in out]`. BTW: Don't used `list` as variable name. It's a python token.

Comment: thank Aguy, when I run that, it gives me a strange output. [['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['2'], ['2']]

Comment: It seems something is wrong with your indention. The `if` clause must be indented under `for`.

Comment: thanks zardosht, yes, that is due to stack overflow formatting, in my actual coding it is indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
# filedata = file.read()
filedata = """10|1|SELL|toaster_1|10.00|20  12|8|BID|toaster_1|7.50 
    13|5|BID|toaster_1|12.50  15|8|SELL|tv_1|250.00|20  16
    17|8|BID|toaster_1|20.00  18|1|BID|tv_1|150.00  19|3|BID|tv_1|200.00 
    20 21|3|BID|tv_1|300.00 """
    
result = []
for i in filedata.split():        #split by space
    result.append(i.split("|"))   #split by `|` and append to result
print(result)
```

---

Or a list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
result = [i.split("|") for i in filedata.split()]
```

**Output:**

```
[['10', '1', 'SELL', 'toaster_1', '10.00', '20'],
 ['12', '8', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '7.50'],
 ['13', '5', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '12.50'],
 ['15', '8', 'SELL', 'tv_1', '250.00', '20'],
 ['16'],
 ['17', '8', 'BID', 'toaster_1', '20.00'],
 ['18', '1', 'BID', 'tv_1', '150.00'],
 ['19', '3', 'BID', 'tv_1', '200.00'],
 ['20'],
 ['21', '3', 'BID', 'tv_1', '300.00']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well your code never handles splitting the line into comma separated values. You just read the line character by character, join all those characters together into a string, and append it to the `out` list.

The following code should work (I minimally changed your own code. I would instead use a more clean solution like the one by [Rakesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63382616/228965)):

```py
import ast

with open('input.txt', 'r') as file :
    filedata = file.read()

    filedata = filedata.replace('|', ',')

    out = []
    buff = []
    for c in filedata :
        if c == '\n':
            line = ''.join(buff)
            for word in line.split(","):
                out.append(word)
            buff = []
        else:
            buff.append(c)
    else:
       if buff:
           out.append(''.join(buff))

    # l = [[i] for i in out]
    print(out)
```

By the way, it is recommended not to use `list` as a variable name.